# Wxpython because the code "plt.pause (0.1)" shows two windows, how to merge into one

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, frame

In the program, after testing, because wxpython originally provided the display of the form, the code "plt.pause(0.1)" will also display a figure form. Finally, the two forms exist at the same time. How can we make the effect in the window of 'plt.pause' is displayed in the wxpython frame window, the code is as follows:

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnnotationBbox,OffsetImage
from PIL import Image
import wx
import time

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
class Canvas(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
            wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
            self.fig=plt.figure()
            self.ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
            self.ax.coastlines()
            self.ax.stock_img()
            self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.fig)

            self.gl = self.ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
                              linewidth=2, color='gray', alpha=15, linestyle='--')
            self.gl.xlabels_top = False
            self.gl.ylabels_left = False
            self.gl.xlines = False
            self.gl.xlocator = mticker.FixedLocator([-180, -45, 0, 45, 180])
            self.gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
            self.gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
            self.gl.xlabel_style = {'size': 15, 'color': 'gray'}
            self.gl.xlabel_style = {'color': 'red', 'weight': 'bold'}
            self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
            self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
            self.Fit()
    def draw(self):
            img=Image.open(r'E:\python_file\untitled\p.png')
            imagebox=OffsetImage(img,zoom=0.05)
            imagebox.image.axes=self.ax
            ab=AnnotationBbox(imagebox,[55,10],pad=0,frameon=False)
            self.ax.add_artist(ab)

    def run(self):
        x,y=55,10
        for i in range(20):
            plt.plot(x,y,'o')

            x=x+7
            y=y+3

            plt.pause(0.1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    fr=wx.Frame(None,title='test')
    panel=Canvas(fr)
    print('fine')
    panel.draw()
    panel.run()
    fr.Show()
    print('just')
    app.MainLoop()
    print('ggg')
```